# Is it possible to include a remote web page in a facelet page?

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, include, server-push, atmosphere

I have a web project using jsf2 implementing a gaming web site on tomcat7. 
When two players want to play against, I would like to insert in the playing web page another page showing the game controls. The included html should come from another server which provides push capabilities through atmosphere framework, receives the moves from the controls, updates the game status and publish the status to all players connected.
The question is: is it possible to include such kind of "window" on a remote server? And how can I do it exploiting jsf2 features?

PS: the server game provides a web service. The hosting server should call the service passing the game id as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facelets is a server side view technology, so it can't do anything for you here.

Just use the HTML `<iframe>` element.

```
<iframe src="http://external.com/game.html?id=#{game.id}"></iframe>
```